# PyQt: most efficient delete sql query

Tags: python, sql, qt, pyqt4

I'm using pyqt4, qt designer and postgresql database. I've managed to make part of my GUI which inserts new data to my db, but now I'd like to try something else for my Delete section of GUI. Since I'm into python/pyqt for maybe a week now I'll try to explain what I'm looking for as simple as possible. First off: here is part of my code which I used for adding data:

```
...
class database_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Main_GUI_Widget):
       def __init__(self):
              QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
              self.setupUi(self)
              self.Add_button.clicked.connect(self.open_sub_ui)

       def open_sub_ui(self):
              if self.Add_comboBox.currentText() == "kirurg":
                     global kirurg
                     kirurg = kirurg_GUI()
                     kirurg.show()
...
class kirurg_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_kirurg_Widget):
       def __init__(self):
              QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
              self.setupUi(self)
              self.kirurg_Add_button.clicked.connect(self.insert_kirurg)

       def insert_kirurg(self):
              oib_kir = self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()
              if not oib_kir:
                     QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', 'oib_kir must not be empty')

              else: 
                     query = QSqlQuery()
                     status = query.exec("INSERT INTO kirurg (oib_kir, prezime, ime, adresa, broj_telefona)"
                                         "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (''.join(self.kirurg_oib_kir_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_prezime_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_ime_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_adresa_lineEdit.text()),
                                                                                    ''.join(self.kirurg_broj_telefona_lineEdit.text())))
                     if status is not True:
                            errorText = query.lastError().text()
                            QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', errorText)
```

So basically, new GUI would open for every other comboBox option. If user selects comboBox option 1 and clicks Add, it opens GUI for adding data to table number 1, if user selects comboBox option 2 and clicks Add, it opens GUI for adding data to table number 2, and so on.
But, I'd like to be more flexibile with my Delete GUI so I was wondering is it possible to make something like this:

```
query.exec("DELETE FROM ('%s') WHERE ('%s) = ('%s'))
```

These ('%s') things should be strings, which my program would read from lineEdit.text(). So basically, program would read data that user enters in lineEdit and according to them it would know which row of data to delete and from which table. I hope you can see my point and question here. If it's not possible, I guess I'll just make another 12 copy pasted GUI's for each table, but I'm hoping there's better solution to that.

Comment: You'd better not building sql queries like that, because of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). Better approach would be to encapsulate database logic into a standalone class(es) and provide `delete` method on them, that would build sql query safely. Also, it might be a good idea to use a more sophisticated db layer than built-in pyQt's

Comment: I kind of knew this isn't the best way to do things, but it's for my college project, so it's not expected of me to do something wow, or even something comepletely correct on my first try. I still have to show this to my professor for the first time so there's probably going to be some changes, but I just hoped there is some better way than the one I used in the "adding" part of the GUI.

Comment: You use QSqlQuery so have a look in the documentation, there a several function (addBindValue(), bindValue(), ...) which are much more saffer and easier to use than what you are trying to do.